# Por que um o value de um input type number e uma string e nao um numero?

Tags: javascript, input, tipagem

Eu estou errado ou se eu pegar com javascript o value de um input type number ele sera uma string e não um numero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É que HTML não tem tipos de dados. Essa questão dos formulários terem um tipo é para que os browsers trabalhem melhor com as informações de cada tipo de formulário.

Quanto ao tipo *number* `<input type="number" ...>`, isso é só para os celulares, *smartphones* mostrarem o teclado numérico na hora de digitar.

Tudo que sai do DOM é mapeado como *string*.